# How can I find out the ratio of negative to positive votes I gave on questions?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how "mean" I've been to newbies and where I would place in a [top like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/query/117684/extreme-downvoters).

I can see all my negative and positive votes on questions individually, as a history, but counting them up manually is too tedious. Is there some script to do this? I mean just for my own account. Is it possible to include deleted questions (I've downvoted) in this statistic too?

Ah, I see I've now made it into that top, just barely with 20% downvotes. I couldn't see myself before, so I assumed it was running of a snapshot or something like that. Still I think that script calculates the ratio over all votes, not just over questions (which is what I'm interested in).

Comment: Note that the vote count you see on the bottom right of your profile’s [activity tab](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/54580/respawned-fluff?tab=topactivity) contains your total number of votes including deleted posts. However, it does not allow you to get the upvote/downvote ratio for questions only.

Comment: (Also, I think that this statistics is rather an indicator of how much you downvote posts that are certain to be deleted such as spam, gibberish, comments as answers and blatantly off-topic questions.)

Comment: Never down-vote spam @Wrzlprmft

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I know, but I am not talking about me here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman why shouldn't I downvote spam, if I also flag it?

Comment: @nick Since that pulls down the post on the question list. We don't want that since it gets out of sight and not cleaned up.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the Community user dowvotes the question with each spam flag. If that pulls the question down, isn't Community acting wrong?

Comment: That is the exception. Those don't count towards pulling it down @nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not available now. The profile page just shows you the number of upvotes and downvotes, and the vote count on questions and answers. There is no statistic on the breakdown level you ask, besides counting manually.

SEDE can't give you the results either, since it doesn't contain votes (since voting is anonymous).

The only thing you can do now is turn this into a feature request, or count your votes by hand.

Comment: Is there no API to access the data from my own profile programmatically? I could easily automate the counting given that.

Comment: There is no mention of votes in the API.

Comment: I see. Thanks for looking into that.